# cfajaxproxy with url rewriting

Tags: javascript, ajax, mod-rewrite, coldfusion

I've been able to successfully implement the cfajaxproxy tag where the cfc in question is located in the root directory of my site.

When a page that is IN the root directory of the site, but is accessed by a rewritten url (eg mysite.com/one/two/ -> mysite.com/two.cfm),  the javascript generated by cfajaxproxy does not point toward the root directory, but uses a relative path to mysite.com/one/two/mycfc.cfc

How can I force cfajaxproxy to look in the root directory first, or otherwise work around this problem?

(I don't want to have to rewrite the specific cfc's url)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some of the code in two.cfm.

Also what are you using to do url rewriting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might wanna keep the path the CFC not part of the URL rewriting, since there's no way to reconfig/remap the url path that cfajaxproxy expects where the cfc should be located.

Or... skip it and use jQuery.